# Grails tag not closed only detected when building WAR

Tags: grails, gsp

I forgot to close a `<g:link>` tag in one of my GSP files.

The application runs perfectly with `grails run-app`, but when I try to execute `grails war`, it says the tag is not closed.

What happens when building the WAR file that is different than when running the app?

**Edit:**

Due to **lukelazarovic**'s answer, I looked a bit more in detail and found that the unclosed tag came form the layout GSP in a plugin that my app uses. The `run-app` command seems to be compiling only my GSP files and not the plugins'. So the compilation errors in layout GSPs come to light when you execute `grails war`.

Comment: try  "grails test-app" and it will fail ;) and this is executed before  war is created

Comment: no, it didn't fail with test-app either, as the GSP was in a plugin used by the app, the only time it is compiled seems to be the war generation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run the app using `grails run-app`, GSPs are compiled on the fly when you access it.

So you would see the error if GSP with unclosed tag is accessed.

In case of `grails war`, all GSPs have to be compiled and put into resulting war file, therefore any error that prevents any GSP to be compiled is revealed.

Comment: I'm just stating the obvious, clean, compile, upgrade, then war is usually what I do whenever I get unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Thanks! It makes sense, but what seems strange, is that the GSP with the error was the main.gsp layout, which should be loaded for every page and therefore fail, but it didn't.

Comment: So the pages are loaded correctly? What is the output of g:link tag then? Edit your question and put there both the unclosed g:link tag from main.gsp and the HTML output please

Comment: There, I edited it with my "latests findings". Hope this helps anyone.